# missing using directive assembly reference error in c# vscode

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

When I try to compile a simple application I made in VSCode with 2 .cs files one with a class, and the other with the main method, I get an error: `cannot find type or namespace "MyClass"`. I do not understand why this happens, as I have put both the main method and class declaration in the same namespace.

MyClass.cs

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classes_test.src
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void testFunc() { Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); }
    }
}```
````

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classes_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

            myClass.testFunc();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the console to print `Hello World!`, but instead I get this error.

Comment: obviously because `MyClass` is in different namespace ... use proper `using` statment

Comment: `MyClass` is in `classes_test.src` namespace according to your code. Just add `using classes_test.src;` and it should work

Comment: then maybe they are independet files not within one project ...

Comment: @Izzy ok, that seemed to fix it. But I don't understand why changing from classes_test.src to classes_test didn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classes_test.src
```

and

```
 classes_test
```

are not the same Namespace.
In order to set your class visible to the main method, you have to use the following using statement.

```
using classes_test.src;
```

This is a quite common mistake, especially for those who are c#-newbie.
Including a namespace, DOES NOT include the subnamespaces